# Get random point on circle on a segment that has a specific heading

Tags: c#, math, vector, geometry

[image: Example]

I have a circle, with a specific radius. Inside the circle I have a point with the X, Y coords. I also have a heading, for example 210. How can I get a random point INSIDE THE CIRCLE on the segment that I draw from the point to the margin of the circle? Thanks!

Comment: Think about solving the problem in polar coordinates...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Doesn't quite work because (X,Y) need not be on the specified heading relative to the center.

Comment: Still, once you know the position on the edge of the circle, picking a random position between two points is easy enough. Just pick a random distance along that line.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman and how would that work. The direction of the heading can also be in the opposite direction like 110 degrees, while the coords are still the same, and I can't find the distance from the X Y point to the outer edge.

Comment: The distance between two points is just Pythagoras theorem. But you don't even need that. First you need to translate your "270 degrees" from polar coordinates to X/Y (basic trig; sin / cos). Then just pick one random double from 0..1 `R`, Then `X3 = X1 + (X2 - X1)*R; Y3 = Y1 + (Y2 - Y1)*R;`. (Basically a weighed average, with a random weight)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        double radiusCircle = 10;
        double y = -3;
        double x = -Math.Sqrt(3 * 9);
        double angleRad = Math.Atan2(y, x);
        double angleDeg = angleRad * 180 / Math.PI;   // 210 (-150) degrees

        double distancePointCenter = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        double distancePointMargin = radiusCircle - distancePointCenter;

        Random rand = new Random(123);

        for (int i = 0 i < 10; i++)
        {   // Generate 10 random points
            double randomPointDistToCenter = distancePointCenter + distancePointMargin * rand.NextDouble();
            double xRandomPoint = randomPointDistToCenter * Math.Cos(angleRad);
            double yRandomPoint = randomPointDistToCenter * Math.Sin(angleRad);
        }
```